# Boolean column(Check box) cell in Infragistics UltraGrid should be disabled based on a condition in InitializeRow event

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

In Infragistics Ultra Grid I have to disable a Boolean (Check box) cell based on a condition in Initialize Row event

PS: I don't want entire column to be disabled. Just only cell should be disabled (cell which contains check box should also be disabled).

I kept code like below

e.Row.Activation = Activation.NoEdit

This code is disabling all the cells in ultra grid row. But a Boolean checkbox which is present in a cell is not getting disabled.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeRow(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{ // deactivate boolean in cell 0
        //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].CellActivation = 
        //         Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.Activation.Disabled;

        e.Row.Cells[0].Activation = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.Activation.Disabled;
}
```

Other choices available beside **Disabled** are: **ActivateOnly**, **AllowEdit**, and **NoEdit**

You can always come back and activate it.

Comment: It will disable only cell. But I want Boolean (Check box) inside a cell should be disabled.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm curious, ultimately will that really make a difference for your needs?

Comment: Yes. I want Boolean (Check box) should be disabled at row level.

Comment: There may not be a way to do it with ultragrid since the checkbox is not a control but defined as a boolean, and the checkbox is created internally. Going to WPF instead of WinForms, it would be a simple matter, but WPF has a learning curve that, from experience, is not a trivial matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea. Instead of a boolean cell, make it a System.Drawing.Bitmap and create your check boxes, checked, and unchecked. 
[image: Checked] [image: Unchecked] and then create/modify an image(s) for disabled.

On the cell click event, change the cell image according to your needs. If need be, create an additional hidden column to store the state/value of the cell. This is something I did when I created/translated a Java version of my c# application to run on other platforms and it worked out great. (Feel free to use these images if it helps)

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause. In base class there is one mouse down event due to which checkbox in ultragrid is being enabled. Even though if i kept logic like this e.Row.Activation = Activation.NoEdit.

Thank you all for your help.